# Why does uploading files to s3 consume a lot of CPU?

Tags: amazon-s3, upload, aws-sdk, cpu

I am writing a service that pull data from some source and upload to `s3` service.
I have tried using it both with `java` and `node`,
using `aws-sdk`.

Both of the test apps are dead simple, just upload a string (size 1kb).

Executing through a threadPool (in java) or just lots of requests (node),
I have reached about 200 req / sec and I see that my `cpu` spiked to 80%, in both apps.

Profiling the `node` app a bit, I found out that the md5 crypto hash takes a lot of cpu ticks.

How can I manage a lot of upload from a backend service?
Why does it take so much `cpu`?

Comment: s3 upload uses md5 crypto to compute the value of etag. It basically computes a hash based on the content you uploading.

Comment: I'm running it through my backend service. Do you know how can I disable it? I have tried all of the flags under `constructor details` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) but nothing helped...

Comment: you cannot disable etag generation. Why is CPU 80% an issue if that's what your service does?